# Examples on a random process with a random argument

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, a random variable $X\in \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and a random process $Y\in \mathbb{R} \to (\Omega \to \mathbb{R})$. I would like to know if there are examples where it makes sense to define a random variable $Z_1\in \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $Z_1(\omega):= Y(X(\omega))(\omega)$, or a random variable $Z_2\in \Omega\to(\Omega \to \mathbb{R})$ given by $Z_2:= Y \circ X$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this notation correctly, the domain of $Y$ is the index set of the process, so $Y(X)$ is its value at a random index. If so, such examples arise very frequently in time-indexed processes where $X$ represents the first time at which some event occurs. For example, $N_t$ could be a Poisson process, and $T$ is the first arrival time (so $N_T\equiv 1$). But $Y$ and $X$ don't need to be related either. For example, $N_t$ and $M_t$ could be two independent Poisson processes, with $T$ being the first arrival time of $N$, and you might be interested in $M_T$.